# How to bypass asset calling limit in pine script

Tags: pine-script

In pine-script if we code any market breadth indicator, it doesn't allow us to call more than 40 scrips. Now NSE NIFTY 50 Index has got 50 constituents. How can I bypass the limit, and code a market breadth indicator with all 50 financial securities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is the limit. There is no bypassing this.

You can add 40 or 25 `input.symbol`s and set them to the specific tickers you need. Then add the same script twice. So, in total you can have information for 50 tickers on your chart. Not with one script though.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will try it, but without the whole capitalization weight distribution in one script, how can I measure the actual divergence?